# how to do hide and show of button inside if else condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zend-framework

i wrote an js function to check a condition by taking the value inserted in text field. if the condition is true i need to hide a button. and again i changed the value in the text field .Then condition is failed, so i want to show the same button without refresh the page. How can i do that?
i tried with below code, its hiding button but after i change input value its not unhiding that same button without refreshing. Once i refresh the page it coming.
The code is giving below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#buy_now_price').keydown(function(){

            var a2=parseInt($('#reserved_price').val());
                    var a3=parseInt($('#Purchased_price').val());
                    var a4=parseInt($('#buy_now_price').val());

                    if(a2 >= a3 && a2 >= a4)
                    {
                        alert("Ensure the minimum price should be lesser than the Purchased and Buy now price");
                        document.getElementById("save").style.display='none';
                        document.getElementById("product").addEventListener("click", function(event){
                            event.preventDefault()

                        });


                    }
                    else{}
            });
    });
         // $("#type option[value='null']").attr("disabled","disabled");

         </script>
```

html part is

```
<form action="<?= $this->form->getAction() ?>" method="<?= $this->form->getMethod() ?>" class="stdform stdform2" id="product" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?= $this->form->employee_id ?>
                <p>
                    <?= $this->form->name ?>
                </p>                            
                <p>
                    <?= $this->form->type ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?= $this->form->brand ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?= $this->form->model ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?= $this->form->condition ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?= $this->form->about ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?= $this->form->listedon ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $this->form->reserved_price; ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $this->form->Purchased_price; ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $this->form->buy_now_price; ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?= $this->form->sale_end_date ?>
                </p>

                <p class="stdformbutton">
                    <?= $this->form->save ?>
                    <?= $this->form->cancel ?>
                </p>    

            </form>
```

Comment: I  see no attempt of hiding or showing any element, you have it commented out. Also this question should have the `php` tag. Remove the `php` tag and add the `jQuery` tag. maybe try `$('#save').hide();` and add `$('#save').show();` in your `else{}`

Comment: Please provide the html as well

Comment: ok i will add it in my question